# IntelliSense Enabled not Reachable

Tags: sql-server-2012, intellisense

So like the title already says I have a problem with IntelliSense,

When I try to enable it it says:
The KeyKombination("ctr+Q",ctr+I") is bound to a Command("IntelliSense Enabled"), that is currently unreachable.

Also The Icon is not enabled,but in the Options it says that it is enabled, but it does nothing.

Any Suggestions what to do?